# Is there a generic reversing of the Arithmetic Mean – Geometric Mean inequality？

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Suppose $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are all positive real numbers. The Arithmetic Mean is $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}$. The Geometric Mean is $\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n x_i}$. Is there a constant $C$ depending on $n$, $\min x_i$, $\max x_i$ such that
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n} \leq C \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n x_i}\ \ ?$$
There is a related question which gives a conclusion but it requires $x_1\,\dots,x_n$ to be non decreasing while $x_1,x_2/2,x_3/3,\dots,x_n/n$ to be non increasing.
[How prove Reversing the Arithmetic mean – Geometric mean inequality？](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205718/how-prove-reversing-the-arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean-inequality)

Is there a generic inequality without any conditions on $x_1,\dots,x_n$ except $x_i>0$?

Comment: A look at the usual upper half unit circle picture for the $n=2$ case shows there are cases where AM is $1$ and GM is as small as one wants.

Comment: Is there a possibility to have the reversed inequality above if $C$ is depending on $n$, $\max\{x_i\}$, and $\min\{x_i\}$?

Comment: Consider $x_1=x$ and all other $x_i=1$, then what you ask for is finding some $C$ s.t $(x+n-1)^n-n^nC^nx \leqslant 0$ for all positive $x$, which clearly isn't possible, the LHS is a polynomial with no upper bound.